# How to monitor ses configuration set event types to grafana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, grafana, amazon-ses

I want to monitor ses event types such as sends, open and click in my grafana dashboard. Is there any way I could send these event types to prometheus?

Comment: Publish SES events https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-using-event-publishing.html and then "transform" these evens to metrics, so they can be ingested into Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure SES to send notifications to an SNS topic which in turn can directly notify a web URL. If you can capture these events on your end you could with relative ease digest this into Prometheus using the relevant format. For general oversite on your SES events there are tools out there (e.g. https://www.sesmonitor.com) which somewhat simplifies the integration and still forwards it to you using web hooks.

You should be able to setup a JSON prometheus data source so once you've got the events hitting your server you could capture/store these and feed them into Prometheus.